# Install Eclipse Json Editor Plugin in Zend Studio 8

Tags: eclipse, json, eclipse-plugin, zend-studio

I'm working on a Zend Framework project, using the JSON configuration.
I want to get a decent editor for JSON. I found [Eclipse Json Editor Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/) on sourceforge. However when I try to install it, Zend Studio says that there are no categorized items.

Can anyone instruct me how to install this plugin, or suggest an other JSON editor plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox on the install screen that says **`"Group items by category"`**.  If you uncheck this you should be able to see the features from the Eclipse Json editor plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that option.